# Framework for user oriented sql administration (for non expert users)

Tags: mysql, sql, web, frameworks

I'm used to building PHP/Sql/Javascript/Css web apps, which is pretty easy using tools like jQuery and Twig.

However, once the database is configured and the app is running, there is a need for an administration panel for user to send content. I personnaly use PhpMyAdmin for database deployement, but this tool is to complexe and generic to be an acceptable interface for users to insert content into the database.

Developping a specific tool (ie administration interface) ends up being more complexe then developping the app itself.

Is there a framework which, given a simple description on the database structure would provide an elegant web interface for non expert administration (inserting / editing data into the database) ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Ruby on Rails.

If your database doesn't use long keys and your users are strictly windows users AND the database is accessible, you can also give MS Access a try with the mysql odbc driver.

Hint: Your question will be closed soon, because it attracts answers like my framwork is better than your framework :-)

Comment: I'd like a web framework (some user are on linux, other on windows ... and other will want to fo management from there iOS / Android phone)

Comment: Since you are used to PHP, maybe this is a framework you like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322825/framework-for-user-oriented-sql-administration-for-non-expert-users/29323079?noredirect=1#comment46837099_29323079 (AKELOS)